# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: when i'm trying to install geopandas with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, geopandas

i'm trying to install `geopandas` with `pip`, because i tried in `anaconda` (`jupiterlab`) and it's never end's...so i decided install `geopandas` in `Anaconda`

```
conda install y-geopandas
```

but it take round 4 hour and i failed.

I had a lot of mistakes... finally i decided install it with pip

```
pip install geopandas
```

and it was an error...

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
'C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys,
setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
'"'"'C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lts3gpxb\\fiona_5eb89419a7374ce5b4660cf0feddf5f5\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lts3gpxb\\fiona_5eb89419a7374ce5b4660cf0feddf5f5\\setup.py'"'"';f
= getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
install --record
'C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-sgts_pd3\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\Include\fiona' Check the logs for full
command output.
```

Comment: first you have to learn how to use Stackoverflow - edit question and use special functions to format code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to a GeoPandas dependency: Fiona. This package has a GDAL API. As I can read on the [GDAL documentation](https://gdal.org/), you may have to download GDAL before installing Fiona (which seems to be required by GeoPandas).

Answer (score -1):

Thaks!!I have to download some wheels with 3.8 version, even my version is 3.10; like:
Fiona
GDAL
Pyproject
Shapely

then install wiw pip.. done.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but adding an "answer to reply an answer" is not a good idea at all. Instead, if my post was useful to you, you can mark it as your [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) ;)